# Flutter LateInitializationError in AlertDialogs

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used the below class for layout variables. And I have called the `init()` method inside the `build` function of my root widget where I have the `MaterialApp`.

```dart
class LayoutConstraints {
  static final LayoutConstraints _singleton = LayoutConstraints._internal();
  factory LayoutConstraints() => _singleton;
  LayoutConstraints._internal();

  MediaQueryData? _mediaQueryData;
  late double _width, _height, _unitHeight, _unitWidth;

  init(BuildContext context) async {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _width = _mediaQueryData!.size.width;
    _height = _mediaQueryData!.size.height - 30;
    _unitWidth = _mediaQueryData!.size.width / 100;
    _unitHeight = _mediaQueryData!.size.height / 100;
  }

  MediaQueryData mediaQuery() => _mediaQueryData!;
  double percentHeight(double percent) => percent * _unitHeight;
  double percentWidth(double percent) => percent * _unitWidth;
}
```

The above implementation works throughout the app but fails when used inside `alertDialog`.

```dart
alertDialog(
  BuildContext context, {
  required String title,
  required String content,
  required String buttonName,
  required VoidCallback onPressed,
}) {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.error_outline, size: 60),
      title: Text(title),
      content: SizedBox(
        width: LayoutConstraints().percentWidth(40.0),
        child: Text(content),
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          child: Text(
            buttonName,
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Calling the above function raises the following error:

```
LateInitializationError: Field '_unitWidth@919436592' has not been initialized.
```

But the method was called before and all the variables have been initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing my code, I found out the mistake I did. I have passed the same context to the alertDialog function but in the builder, I have mistakenly initiated a new context. Once I changed the builder method from

> builder: (BuildContext context){} to builder: (context){}

everything works.

@TheSylar I understand the complexities in singleton pattern but for my use case, the LayoutConstraints class will be initiated only once at the app startup and will be accessed by many widgets throughout the app. So, a singleton class will work good here.